# What's wrong with my implementation of the nearest neighbour algorithm (for the TSP)?

Tags: java, algorithm, nearest-neighbor, traveling-salesman

I was tasked with implementing the [nearest neighbour algorithm for the travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm). It was said that the method should try starting from every city and return the best tour found. According to the auto-marking program, my implementation works correctly for the most basic case, but only works partially for all more advanced cases.

I don't understand where I went wrong, and am seeking a review of my code for correctness. I am keen to find out where I went wrong and what the correct approach would be.

My Java code is as follows:

```
/*
 * Returns the shortest tour found by exercising the NN algorithm 
 * from each possible starting city in table.
 * table[i][j] == table[j][i] gives the cost of travel between City i and City j.
 */
 public static int[] tspnn(double[][] table) {
     
     // number of vertices 
     int numberOfVertices = table.length;
     // the Hamiltonian cycle built starting from vertex i
     int[] currentHamiltonianCycle = new int[numberOfVertices];
     // the lowest total cost Hamiltonian cycle
     double lowestTotalCost = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
     //  the shortest Hamiltonian cycle
     int[] shortestHamiltonianCycle = new int[numberOfVertices];
     
     // consider each vertex i as a starting point
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
         /* 
          * Consider all vertices that are reachable from the starting point i,
          * thereby creating a new current Hamiltonian cycle.
          */
         for (int j = 0; j < numberOfVertices; j++) {
             /* 
              * The modulo of the sum of i and j allows us to account for the fact 
              * that Java indexes arrays from 0.
              */
             currentHamiltonianCycle[j] = (i + j) % numberOfVertices;   
         }
         for (int j = 1; j < numberOfVertices - 1; j++) {
             int nextVertex = j;
             for (int p = j + 1; p < numberOfVertices; p++) {
                 if (table[currentHamiltonianCycle[j - 1]][currentHamiltonianCycle[p]] < table[currentHamiltonianCycle[j - 1]][currentHamiltonianCycle[nextVertex]]) {
                           nextVertex = p;
                 }
             }
             
             int a = currentHamiltonianCycle[nextVertex];
             currentHamiltonianCycle[nextVertex] = currentHamiltonianCycle[j];
             currentHamiltonianCycle[j] = a;
         }
         
         /*
          * Find the total cost of the current Hamiltonian cycle.
          */
         double currentTotalCost = table[currentHamiltonianCycle[0]][currentHamiltonianCycle[numberOfVertices - 1]];
         for (int z = 0; z < numberOfVertices - 1; z++) {
             currentTotalCost += table[currentHamiltonianCycle[z]][currentHamiltonianCycle[z + 1]];
         }
         
         if (currentTotalCost < lowestTotalCost) {
             lowestTotalCost = currentTotalCost;
             shortestHamiltonianCycle = currentHamiltonianCycle;
         }
     }
     return shortestHamiltonianCycle;
 }
```

---

### Edit

I've gone through this code with pen and paper for a simple example, and I can't find any problems with the algorithm implementation. Based on this, it seems to me that it should work in the general case.

---

### Edit 2

I have tested my implementation with the following mock example:

```
double[][] table = {{0, 2.3, 1.8, 4.5}, {2.3, 0, 0.4, 0.1}, 
                {1.8, 0.4, 0, 1.3}, {4.5, 0.1, 1.3, 0}};
```

It seems to produce the expected output for the nearest neighbour algorithm, which is 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0

I am now wondering whether the auto-marking program is incorrect, or whether it's just that my implementation does not work in the general case.

Comment: First hint: have a method that selects the starting point. Then have a methods that runs the algorithm based on the selected starting point. This way you keep two different things in two different methods. Second hint: use object oriented code if possible. Shooting around with array indices makes things horribly difficult to write+understand+maintain. Third: I assume you always select the same sequence of vertices, just with different starting indices. Fourth: you always re-use `currentHamiltonianCycle` array, thus overwriting the old results. You should allocate that inside the `for i` loop.

Comment: @JayC667 I wanted to use OOP principles with separate methods, but I was told that it must all be written in a single method for the auto-marker, so that's why it's written this way.

Comment: @JayC667 Hmm, I'm not sure I understand what you're referring to. `currentHamiltonianCycle` is allocated once at the beginning and then within the `for i` loop when it does `shortestHamiltonianCycle = currentHamiltonianCycle;`.

Comment: Exactly. And the `=` operator DOES NOT COPY the array contents, it only assigns the reference to the array, so you're always working on the same array, overwriting the previous way/result. Use something like `System.arrayCopy()` if you wanna copy its values.

Comment: I don't know, tbh. Sorry. This code is too convoluted for me to understand without deeply analyzing and running it in debug mode. This all looks like a mathematician's work. From the setup, how you do things, the `auto-marker` you seem to be using, with strange limitations, yet you decided to use Java (which is only 50% as fast as C or C++ or any other language that does no array index checking). So this all is too far away from the solutions I know and can see from the get-go.

Comment: @JayC667 I have tested some mock examples, and it seems that my implementation is producing the correct result, so I actually don't think having `=` instead of `System.arrayCopy()` is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have stated in my comments, I see one **basic problem** with the algorithm itself:

- It will NOT properly permute the towns, but always work in sequence (A-B-C-D-A-B-C-D, start anywhere and take 4)

To **prove that problem**, I wrote the following code for testing and setting up simple and advanced examples.

- Please first configure it via the `static public final` constants, before you change the code itself.
- Focusing on the simple example: if the algorithm worked fine, the result would always be either A-B-C-D or D-C-B-A.
- But as you can observe with the output, the algorithm will not select the (globally) best tour, because it does its permutations of tested towns wrong.

I've added in my own Object-Oriented implementation to showcase:

- problems with selections, which is really hard to do properly in ONE method all at once
- how the OO style has its advantages
- that proper testing/developing is quite easy to set up and perform (I'm not even using Unit tests here, that would be the next step to verify/validate algorithms)

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class TSP_NearestNeighbour {



    static public final int NUMBER_OF_TEST_RUNS = 4;

    static public final boolean GENERATE_SIMPLE_TOWNS = true;

    static public final int NUMBER_OF_COMPLEX_TOWNS         = 10;
    static public final int DISTANCE_RANGE_OF_COMPLEX_TOWNS = 100;



    static private class Town {
        public final String Name;
        public final int    X;
        public final int    Y;
        public Town(final String pName, final int pX, final int pY) {
            Name = pName;
            X = pX;
            Y = pY;
        }
        public double getDistanceTo(final Town pOther) {
            final int dx = pOther.X - X;
            final int dy = pOther.Y - Y;
            return Math.sqrt(Math.abs(dx * dx + dy * dy));
        }
        @Override public int hashCode() { // not really needed here
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + X;
            result = prime * result + Y;
            return result;
        }
        @Override public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) return true;
            if (obj == null) return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
            final Town other = (Town) obj;
            if (X != other.X) return false;
            if (Y != other.Y) return false;
            return true;
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return Name + " (" + X + "/" + Y + ")";
        }
    }

    static private double[][] generateDistanceTable(final ArrayList<Town> pTowns) {
        final double[][] ret = new double[pTowns.size()][pTowns.size()];
        for (int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < pTowns.size(); outerIndex++) {
            final Town outerTown = pTowns.get(outerIndex);

            for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < pTowns.size(); innerIndex++) {
                final Town innerTown = pTowns.get(innerIndex);

                final double distance = outerTown.getDistanceTo(innerTown);
                ret[outerIndex][innerIndex] = distance;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }



    static private ArrayList<Town> generateTowns_simple() {
        final Town a = new Town("A", 0, 0);
        final Town b = new Town("B", 1, 0);
        final Town c = new Town("C", 2, 0);
        final Town d = new Town("D", 3, 0);
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d));
    }
    static private ArrayList<Town> generateTowns_complex() {
        final ArrayList<Town> allTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COMPLEX_TOWNS; i++) {
            final int randomX = (int) (Math.random() * DISTANCE_RANGE_OF_COMPLEX_TOWNS);
            final int randomY = (int) (Math.random() * DISTANCE_RANGE_OF_COMPLEX_TOWNS);
            final Town t = new Town("Town-" + (i + 1), randomX, randomY);
            if (allTowns.contains(t)) { // do not allow different towns at same location!
                System.out.println("Towns colliding at " + t);
                --i;
            } else {
                allTowns.add(t);
            }
        }
        return allTowns;
    }
    static private ArrayList<Town> generateTowns() {
        if (GENERATE_SIMPLE_TOWNS) return generateTowns_simple();
        else return generateTowns_complex();
    }



    static private void printTowns(final ArrayList<Town> pTowns, final double[][] pDistances) {
        System.out.println("Towns:");
        for (final Town town : pTowns) {
            System.out.println("\t" + town);
        }

        System.out.println("Distance Matrix:");
        for (int y = 0; y < pDistances.length; y++) {
            System.out.print("\t");
            for (int x = 0; x < pDistances.length; x++) {
                System.out.print(pDistances[y][x] + " (" + pTowns.get(y).Name + "-" + pTowns.get(x).Name + ")" + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }



    private static void testAlgorithm() {
        final ArrayList<Town> towns = generateTowns();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TEST_RUNS; i++) {
            final double[][] distances = generateDistanceTable(towns);
            printTowns(towns, distances);

            {
                final int[] path = tspnn(distances);
                System.out.println("tspnn Path:");
                for (int pathIndex = 0; pathIndex < path.length; pathIndex++) {
                    final Town t = towns.get(pathIndex);
                    System.out.println("\t" + t);
                }
            }
            {
                final ArrayList<Town> path = tspnn_simpleNN(towns);
                System.out.println("tspnn_simpleNN Path:");
                for (final Town t : path) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + t);
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }

            // prepare for for next run. We do this at the end of the loop so we can only print first config
            Collections.shuffle(towns);
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        testAlgorithm();
    }



    /*
     * Returns the shortest tour found by exercising the NN algorithm
     * from each possible starting city in table.
     * table[i][j] == table[j][i] gives the cost of travel between City i and City j.
     */
    public static int[] tspnn(final double[][] table) {

        // number of vertices
        final int numberOfVertices = table.length;
        // the Hamiltonian cycle built starting from vertex i
        final int[] currentHamiltonianCycle = new int[numberOfVertices];
        // the lowest total cost Hamiltonian cycle
        double lowestTotalCost = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        //  the shortest Hamiltonian cycle
        int[] shortestHamiltonianCycle = new int[numberOfVertices];

        // consider each vertex i as a starting point
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
            /*
             * Consider all vertices that are reachable from the starting point i,
             * thereby creating a new current Hamiltonian cycle.
             */
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfVertices; j++) {
                /*
                 * The modulo of the sum of i and j allows us to account for the fact
                 * that Java indexes arrays from 0.
                 */
                currentHamiltonianCycle[j] = (i + j) % numberOfVertices;
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < numberOfVertices - 1; j++) {
                int nextVertex = j;
                for (int p = j + 1; p < numberOfVertices; p++) {
                    if (table[currentHamiltonianCycle[j - 1]][currentHamiltonianCycle[p]] < table[currentHamiltonianCycle[j - 1]][currentHamiltonianCycle[nextVertex]]) {
                        nextVertex = p;
                    }
                }

                final int a = currentHamiltonianCycle[nextVertex];
                currentHamiltonianCycle[nextVertex] = currentHamiltonianCycle[j];
                currentHamiltonianCycle[j] = a;
            }

            /*
             * Find the total cost of the current Hamiltonian cycle.
             */
            double currentTotalCost = table[currentHamiltonianCycle[0]][currentHamiltonianCycle[numberOfVertices - 1]];
            for (int z = 0; z < numberOfVertices - 1; z++) {
                currentTotalCost += table[currentHamiltonianCycle[z]][currentHamiltonianCycle[z + 1]];
            }

            if (currentTotalCost < lowestTotalCost) {
                lowestTotalCost = currentTotalCost;
                shortestHamiltonianCycle = currentHamiltonianCycle;
            }
        }
        return shortestHamiltonianCycle;
    }



    /**
     * Here come my basic implementations.
     * They can be heavily (heavily!) improved, but are verbose and direct to show the logic behind them
     */



    /**
     * <p>example how to implement the NN solution th OO way</p>
     * we could also implement
     * <ul>
     * <li>a recursive function</li>
     * <li>or one with running counters</li>
     * <li>or one with a real map/route objects, where further optimizations can take place</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    public static ArrayList<Town> tspnn_simpleNN(final ArrayList<Town> pTowns) {
        ArrayList<Town> bestRoute = null;
        double bestCosts = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        for (final Town startingTown : pTowns) {
            //setup
            final ArrayList<Town> visitedTowns = new ArrayList<>(); // ArrayList because we need a stable index
            final HashSet<Town> unvisitedTowns = new HashSet<>(pTowns); // all towns are available at start; we use HashSet because we need fast search; indexing plays not role here

            // step 1
            Town currentTown = startingTown;
            visitedTowns.add(currentTown);
            unvisitedTowns.remove(currentTown);

            // steps 2-n
            while (unvisitedTowns.size() > 0) {
                // find nearest town
                final Town nearestTown = findNearestTown(currentTown, unvisitedTowns);
                if (nearestTown == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Something in the code is wrong...");

                currentTown = nearestTown;
                visitedTowns.add(currentTown);
                unvisitedTowns.remove(currentTown);
            }

            // selection
            final double cost = getCostsOfRoute(visitedTowns);
            if (cost < bestCosts) {
                bestCosts = cost;
                bestRoute = visitedTowns;
            }
        }
        return bestRoute;
    }



    static private Town findNearestTown(final Town pCurrentTown, final HashSet<Town> pSelectableTowns) {
        double minDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Town minTown = null;

        for (final Town checkTown : pSelectableTowns) {
            final double dist = pCurrentTown.getDistanceTo(checkTown);
            if (dist < minDist) {
                minDist = dist;
                minTown = checkTown;
            }
        }

        return minTown;
    }
    static private double getCostsOfRoute(final ArrayList<Town> pTowns) {
        double costs = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < pTowns.size(); i++) { // use pre-index
            final Town t1 = pTowns.get(i - 1);
            final Town t2 = pTowns.get(i);
            final double cost = t1.getDistanceTo(t2);
            costs += cost;
        }
        return costs;
    }



}
```

This, at an unchanged state, gives us outputs similar to the following:

```
Towns:
    A (0/0)
    B (1/0)
    C (2/0)
    D (3/0)
Distance Matrix:
    0.0 (A-A)   1.0 (A-B)   2.0 (A-C)   3.0 (A-D)   
    1.0 (B-A)   0.0 (B-B)   1.0 (B-C)   2.0 (B-D)   
    2.0 (C-A)   1.0 (C-B)   0.0 (C-C)   1.0 (C-D)   
    3.0 (D-A)   2.0 (D-B)   1.0 (D-C)   0.0 (D-D)   
tspnn Path:
    A (0/0)
    B (1/0)
    C (2/0)
    D (3/0)
tspnn_simpleNN Path:
    A (0/0)
    B (1/0)
    C (2/0)
    D (3/0)


Towns:
    C (2/0)
    D (3/0)
    B (1/0)
    A (0/0)
Distance Matrix:
    0.0 (C-C)   1.0 (C-D)   1.0 (C-B)   2.0 (C-A)   
    1.0 (D-C)   0.0 (D-D)   2.0 (D-B)   3.0 (D-A)   
    1.0 (B-C)   2.0 (B-D)   0.0 (B-B)   1.0 (B-A)   
    2.0 (A-C)   3.0 (A-D)   1.0 (A-B)   0.0 (A-A)   
tspnn Path:
    C (2/0)
    D (3/0)
    B (1/0)
    A (0/0)
tspnn_simpleNN Path:
    D (3/0)
    C (2/0)
    B (1/0)
    A (0/0)


Towns:
    D (3/0)
    B (1/0)
    C (2/0)
    A (0/0)
Distance Matrix:
    0.0 (D-D)   2.0 (D-B)   1.0 (D-C)   3.0 (D-A)   
    2.0 (B-D)   0.0 (B-B)   1.0 (B-C)   1.0 (B-A)   
    1.0 (C-D)   1.0 (C-B)   0.0 (C-C)   2.0 (C-A)   
    3.0 (A-D)   1.0 (A-B)   2.0 (A-C)   0.0 (A-A)   
tspnn Path:
    D (3/0)
    B (1/0)
    C (2/0)
    A (0/0)
tspnn_simpleNN Path:
    D (3/0)
    C (2/0)
    B (1/0)
    A (0/0)


Towns:
    A (0/0)
    B (1/0)
    C (2/0)
    D (3/0)
Distance Matrix:
    0.0 (A-A)   1.0 (A-B)   2.0 (A-C)   3.0 (A-D)   
    1.0 (B-A)   0.0 (B-B)   1.0 (B-C)   2.0 (B-D)   
    2.0 (C-A)   1.0 (C-B)   0.0 (C-C)   1.0 (C-D)   
    3.0 (D-A)   2.0 (D-B)   1.0 (D-C)   0.0 (D-D)   
tspnn Path:
    A (0/0)
    B (1/0)
    C (2/0)
    D (3/0)
tspnn_simpleNN Path:
    A (0/0)
    B (1/0)
    C (2/0)
    D (3/0)
```

As you can see, your algorithm is severely dependent on the sequence of input/towns. If the algorithm was correct, the result would always be A-B-C-D or D-C-B-A.

So use this 'testing' framework to improve your code. The method you provided `tspnn()` does not rely on the other code, so once you improved your code, you can comment out all my stuff. Or put this all in another class, and call your real implementation across classes. As it's `static public`, you can easily call it via `YourClassName.tspnn(distances)`.

On the other hand, maybe see if you can improve the *auto-marking program*, so you can go full Java without problems.